# Mostrar DIV cuando la URL coincida

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo estas 2 URL de una página hecha en WordPress + WooCommerce

> https:// paginaweb.com/finalizar-compra/
>
> https://
> paginaweb.com/finalizar-compra/order-pay/874/?key=wc_order_dFD88wKOHAwWW

La primera URL es estática y la segunda cambia con cada pedido nuevo a partir de "order-pay/"

He intentado con el siguiente código que esconda un DIV cuando la URL contiene "order-pay"

```
 <div id="mydiv">LOREM IPSUM</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("order-pay") != -1) {
 $("#mydiv").hide();
 }
 </script>
```

Pero se muestra en las dos páginas indistintamente.

Cabe destacar que el código de la página finalizar compra estática también se carga en ***order-pay/...*** por ello quiero que el div que muestro en ***finalizar-compra*** cuando esta cambie a la URL ***finalizar-compra/order-pay/...*** desaparezca.

Comment: cómo se inserta ese div? dónde aparece? con esa info tendrías que revisar los hooks disponibles y/o editar el template del checkout y probar testear `if is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' )` y ahi meter un css inline o directamente no imprimir el div

Answer (score 0):

En realidad podrías hacerlo sin necesidad de usar javascript, solo con css, WordPress y en este caso Woocommerce tienden a agregar clases al body del DOM, por lo que puedes aprovechar estas clases para mostrar u ocultar elementos, por ejemplo, en la página de inicio una de las clases son la clase home y cada página tiene la clase page-{id}, estas son algunas de las clases de las páginas de Woocommerce

Tienda de Woocommerce

```
.woocommerce-shop
```

Detalles del producto

```
.single-product
```

Carrito

```
.woocommerce-cart
```

Finalizar Compra

```
.woocommerce-checkout
```

Página de agradecimiento - Order Received

```
.woocommerce-order-received
```

Pagina Order Pay

```
.woocommerce-order-pay
```

Mi cuenta

```
.woocommerce-account
```

Por lo que basado en eso puedes hacer algo como

```
body.woocommerce-order-pay #mydiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, el problema es que no se puede editar la pagina de order-pay, solo la de finalizar compra, por lo tanto tengo que desde finalizar compra esconder el div de las urls order-pay, a no ser que haya un archivo php o algo en woocomerce del order-pay. el codigo de order-pay es el mismo que finalizar compra, woocomerce esconde los campos de datos del cliente al pasar a order pay pero no el codigo personalizado que se inserte.